# what is the algorithm that will give me O(logd)

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, time-complexity

the question is " Suggest an algorithm that takes a sorted Array and X , and it will return the index of X in the Array if it's not found in the array return -1 , the Time Complexity of the algorithm should be O(log d ) while d is the number of elements that are smaller than X

I cant think of something other than looking at the middle index and compare it if it smaller or bigger than X , then do the same thing recursively . but i don't think it is O(log d ) . I have a homework to submit and I don't know what to do .

Comment: Have you checked basic search algorithms? As a hint, your log is of base 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Exponential search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_search) is *O(log d)*.

Starting at `upper = 0`, compare the value `array[upper]` to `value`. If it is less than `value`, update `upper = (upper + 1) * 2;` until `array[upper] >= value`. If it is equal, then return `upper`, otherwise perform a [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) between `[upper / 2, upper)`.

In JavaScript it would look like this:

```js
function exponentialSearch (array, value) {
  let upper = 0;
  // exponential gallop
  while (array[upper] < value) upper = (upper + 1) * 2;

  if (array[upper] === value) return upper;
  // binary search
  for (let lower = upper / 2; upper > lower; ) {
    const bisect = lower + Math.floor((upper - lower) / 2);

    if (array[bisect] > value) upper = bisect;
    else if (array[bisect] < value) lower = bisect;
    else return bisect;
  }

  return -1;
}
```

Comment: That is indeed in O(log *d*).